# Creating button next to "add media" that allows you to choose a single post

Tags: plugins, customization, admin, visual-editor

I'm looking to create a button next to "add media" ( much like gravity forms "add form) that allows you to choose a custom post and then inserts that post id into a shortcode.

I've bene looking at hooking into tinymce for the longest time, but realized that that wasn't the way to go (as those buttons aren't a part of the tinymce editor).

anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I just found this link: http://themergency.com/adding-custom-buttons-to-the-wordpress-content-editor-part-1/ which lets me create the button and allows me to populate the the popup box with the posts I want, now I just need to put the posts id (which I have) into a shortcode in the post. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Brucep, WPSE is questions / answer format , it's best to show us what you tried and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 5):

For WP versions before `3.5.0`, use the `media_buttons_context` filter:

```
add_filter( 'media_buttons_context', function($context ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'page.php', 'post-new.php', 'post-edit.php' ) ) ) {
        $context .= '<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>';
    }

    return $context;
} );
```

For 3.5.0+, use the `media_buttons` action:

```
add_action( 'media_buttons', function($editor_id){
    echo '<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>';
} );
```

Both will add a button beside the "Add Media" button above the post editor.